# SSIS package runs in cmd line but not in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cmd, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

When running the DTSX file via cmd line with this line:

`C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /F C:\DTSX\MyDTSX_File.dtsx`

This returns a table with the values that I requested from the DTSX.

When I then try to run this command within MS SQL Server Management Studios it returns the table with no values inside of it. The command looks like this:

`EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /F C:\DTSX\MyDTSX_File.dtsx'`

This was all working fine until we moved over to 2019.
This is the 32-bit version of MS SQL 2008R2.

Here are the error messages that MS SQL returns:

=================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your package references a "J:" drive, which probably is not mapped for the SQL Agent Service account. Try with a UNC path (assuming the account does have access to the folder of course).

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick. I'll just need to cut out any refernce to the the J: drive and replace it with the IP/MachineName and the rest of the file path thanks. I thought I tried that earlier and it didn't work but now it does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that was that the DTSX was mapped to a network drive.
The solution is to change it from J: to it's actual IP Address/ MachineName followed with the path name you want to store it at.